# Line between the text in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't get the result a paragraph in html and css.
I'd like to set 2 lines (or 2 borders) between a text, like this:

```
---- TEXT ----
```

How can I do this using CSS or something like that?

Comment: Two lines _between_ the text? Your example has lines before and after the text.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to do this using somenthing like <hr>. A big <hr> with a text in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

You can try with :[before](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp) and [:after](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp) pseudo elements like this:

**html**

```
<p>Test</p>
```

**css**

```
p:before{
    content:"----";
}

p:after{
    content:"----";
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jxd9T/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick and easy way, so long as your background is a solid color.

HTML:

```
<p class="myCopy">
    <span>My Text goes here</span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.myCopy {
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
    text-align: center;
}

.myCopy span {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Adjust the height value of .myCopy to move the line up and down. Change the background color of the inner span to match the primary background color.

EDIT: here's a fiddle - [FIDDLE!!!](http://jsfiddle.net/znVEL/)

Answer (score 1):

From the top answer of [CSS Title with Horizontal Line on either side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15557694/1366033)

How about this:

```html
<h1 class='strikearound'>Lined Title</h1>
```

```css
h1.strikearound {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
h1.strikearound:before, h1.strikearound:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 51%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    content: '\a0';
    background-color: grey;
}
h1.strikearound:before {
    margin-left: -50%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

#### [Demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/XWVxk/499/)

What's nice is it doesn't rely on any particular background color

**Screenshot**:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a paragraph `<p>` or a line-break `<br>` tag to separate text.
Additionally, a horizontal rule `<hr>` tag will create a horizontal line to separate text.

Comment: You don't appear to have understood the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: relative` to move children on bottom border for solid color.

Html:

```
<p class="myCopy">
    <span>My Text goes here</span>
</p>
```

Css:

```
.myCopy {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
    text-align: center;
}

.myCopy span {
    position:relative;
    bottom: -10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Styled version:
http://jsfiddle.net/UnG4T/1/

Or you can use 100% width `:after` and `:before` with negative margin for other bg

```
.myCopy {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.myCopy::before, .myCopy::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}

.myCopy::before{
    margin-left: -100%;
}

.myCopy span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Styled version:
http://jsfiddle.net/UnG4T/3/